# Manually Backing Up Locked-down Outlook 2003 SP3

Tags: batch, microsoft-outlook-2003

My work has a terrible implementation of NTLogins, Profiles and Outlook 2003 Service Pack 3.

Everyday I have to change move and chose all kinds of stuff. I did some digging and found where some of the settings in outlook are stored.

I have created a [batch file](http://code.google.com/p/callcenterprogram/downloads/list) that I run every day to open my default programs, associate a printer and load **some** of my Outlook settings. The ones I have found locations for are as follows.

- Toolbar Arrangement
- AutoComplete list
- Rules
- Signatures

What I need to find is some or all of the location to backup settings (or where they are stored) for the following.

- Default Selected Fonts
- Default Selected Signature (my script just loads them, it doesn't select)
- Window size/position
- Status Bar (visible or not)
- Default Reminder length in calendar
- Message compose options (Mail Format Tab in options)
- "Always spell check before sending"
- "Empty the deleted Items folder upon exiting"
- Options>Other>General>Advanced Options> Startup in this folder:
- Whether I want to participate in the user feedback thingy (prompts me everyday)

Any/All help appreciated

Comment: What I know so far:
%USERPROFILE%\Application Data\Microsoft\Outlook - settings
%USERPROFILE%\Application Data\Microsoft\Signatures - signatures

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The article [Outlook 2003 configurations and file locations](http://www.adminspy.com/Windows-Tips/Outlook-configurations-and-file-locations.html) contains an enormous list of places where Outlook 2003 settings are stored (except mail settings).

Mail settings are stored in the registry at:
`HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Office\11.0\Common\MailSettings`
However, as some (but not all) settings are in binary, the most one can do is export and re-import these problematic settings. They don't seem to be encoded, so it might be possible to study their structure.

You can also use the [Save My Settings Wizard](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/826809) to save and restore almost all Outlook settings. As it is a GUI program, to have it run automatically you might need to automate its startup with AutoHotkey or another macro program.

In any case, the above article also includes a complete list of the registry keys that are saved, which can point you in the right direction even if you decide not to use the wizard.

Comment: Making me wait 29 minutes to give you the bounty. You win!  Might be more work than I want to take on, but you got the answer.